# How do I set off a chain of command blocks if a players health goes to a certain health. (Java, 1.17)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want a chain of command blocks to go off if a player or entities health drops to a certain number. When I try it, it doesn't set off the command blocks, or it doesn't even set off at all.

Comment: in the future, please give us more to work off of by giving us examples of what you've tried, and what happens; "it doesn't set off the command blocks, or it doesn't even set off at all" doesn't help us

Comment: ok im sorry, i didn't know

Answer (score 2):

### Setup:

- `scoreboard objectives add Health dummy`
- Tag the entity you want to track. In this answer, the tag `myEntity` will be used.
- You should also know how much health your entity
  has. Use `/data get entity @e[tag=myEntity] Health`

### Command blocks:

**`Repeating`, `Unconditional`:**

```
execute as @e[tag=myEntity] store result score @s Health run data get entity @s Health
```

**`Chain`, `Unconditional`, `Always Active`:**

```
execute if score @e[tag=myEntity,tag=!health_reached,limit=1] Health matches 20..40
```

**`Chain`, `Conditional`, `Always Active`:**

```
tag @e[tag=myEntity] add health_reached
```

**`Chain`, `Unconditional`, `Always Active`:**

```
say myEntity has between 20 and 40 Health
```

Your command blocks should look like this:
[image: A command block chain, including repeating, chain-unconditional, and chain-conditional command blocks.]

You can add more **`Chain`, `Unconditional`, `Always Active`** blocks to the end of the chain to have more things happen when `myEntity` reaches 20-40 Health.

Comment: The second command block doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: My bad. The command only allows 1 entity, but the selector allows more than one. Use `execute if score @e[tag=myEntity,limit=1] Health matches 20..40` instead. Answer edited. I also changed the first command, there was an error as well.

Comment: It still spams the command when he isn't at that health, it only stops when he dies

Comment: @MilkAppreciate Answer edited.